# How to assign a div class to an element based on url in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django 
I am currently doing this:

```
<a class="{% if request.path == '/messages/' %}current{% endif %}"
```

To style a nav link, or to make it bolder indicating that you are on that page currently.

The problem with this is that it only works when the user is at the main inbox, as soon as they click to view a message, the styling for that nav link disappears because they are no longer on /messages/, but on /messages/4/ instead.

How can I adjust my code above so that anything after /messages/  does not matter?  Can I add an asterisk, like:

```
<a class="{% if request.path == '/messages/*/' %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly simple way to do this is to pass in context data from the view instead of using the `request.path`. Here is a similar example that deals with li items.

```
<ul>
    <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab1' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab2' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab3' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In your example, in your "all messages" and "single messages" view, you would pass context so the template would know where to apply your `current` class.

Comment: So in this example, in my views I would put active_tab = 'tab1' and then pass it through the context?

Comment: Yeah, you can change the name of the context variable name, but that's the idea.